# Can I render pages on screen with proper print-like page-break?

Tags: css, screen, page-break

I'm ready to learn anything need to render my page looks like A4 printed.

I know how to use css @media query but not fully understand.. (keep learning specification..)

How can I make my page do page-break automatically?

It's not possible only with css? I think I can handle with js but this looks something weird..

Comment: Try this -> https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use page-break-after or page-break-before css rule, whichever is more convenient on your html.

```
@media print {
    <your element> {page-break-after: always;}
}
```